# Debugging slow cygwin bash startup

Tags: bash, cygwin, strace

Running:

```
strace bash -li
```

and grepping for `CreateProcessW`:

```
  182  590565 [main] bash 512 frok::parent: CreateProcessW (C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, 0, 0, 1, 0x420, 0, 0, 0xFFFFA1A0, 0xFFFFA140)
  112   82709 [main] bash 513 frok::parent: CreateProcessW (C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, 0, 0, 1, 0x420, 0, 0, 0xFFFF9FC0, 0xFFFF9F60)
  102 1174395 [main] bash 512 frok::parent: CreateProcessW (C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, 0, 0, 1, 0x420, 0, 0, 0xFFFFBAB0, 0xFFFFBA50)
  136   80996 [main] bash 515 frok::parent: CreateProcessW (C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, 0, 0, 1, 0x420, 0, 0, 0xFFFFB8D0, 0xFFFFB870)
  124 1751509 [main] bash 512 frok::parent: CreateProcessW (C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, 0, 0, 1, 0x420, 0, 0, 0xFFFFA0F0, 0xFFFFA090)
  182   82201 [main] bash 517 frok::parent: CreateProcessW (C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, 0, 0, 1, 0x420, 0, 0, 0xFFFF9F10, 0xFFFF9EB0)
  139 2209867 [main] bash 512 frok::parent: CreateProcessW (C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, 0, 0, 1, 0x420, 0, 0, 0xFFFFA0F0, 0xFFFFA090)
  129   78080 [main] bash 519 frok::parent: CreateProcessW (C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe, 0, 0, 1, 0x420, 0, 0, 0xFFFF9F10, 0xFFFF9EB0)
```

So there are a few executions that as you can see take a bunch of time. I'm trying to figure out what's is being started, so I can try to reduce the startup time. However, it just shows the exe, not the arguments, so it's hard to troubleshoot.

Is there a way to make `strace` output the arguments? Or any other way to do that if `strace` doesn't support it?

Comment: It is part of the fork call, there are no arguments. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html

Comment: Recently had a slow startup on Windows caused by a command prompt (PS1) that was using `__git_ps1`.

Comment: Thanks @matzeri, do you know which one would carry the arguments?

Comment: Thanks @xenoid, in my case it seems it's not related to PS1, but to running a few instances of bash as per above.

Comment: Any of this program installed https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda ? Usually these and similar  are responsible for slowing or worse